# How to properly preload CSS stylesheets?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to improve my website's performance by preloading stylesheets but I don't know what's the best way to do it. I have never used this feature before.

I found the following ways, to me all look the same after some testing I did.

```
<!-- 1 -->

<link rel="preload stylesheet" href="style.css" as="style">


<!-- 2 -->

<link rel="preload" href="style.css" as="style">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">


<!-- 3 -->

<link rel="preload" href="style.css" as="style" onload='this.rel="stylesheet"'>
<noscript>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</noscript>


<!-- 4 -->

<link rel="preload" href="style.css" as="style" onload='this.onload=null;this.rel="stylesheet"'>
<noscript>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</noscript>
```

I'd preferably like to use the first one because looks the most elegant.

What's in your opinion is the most proper way?

Are they all exactly the same?

Do you know a better way?

Answer (score 1):

I usually use the second method unless my customer specifically requests a different one. Since the second method is the one recommended by MDN, I've gotten used to it personally.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Link_types/preload